# Building an VM with Vagrant and connecting with ssh+2FA to protect a bitcoin wallet?

Tags: encryption, authentication, ssh, virtualization, bitcoin

I would like to try to build a Virtualbox image to use with Vagrant. This is the features:

- Login with SSH + 2FA (Google Auth)
- No X
- No internet connection
- Copy unsigned transaction, sign it and broadcast from the external host
- (Possible with the use of "Synced Folders")

What worries me is:

If the image was to be stolen and the hacker could mount the image and access my wallet that way, would the solution be to encrypt something?

I really like the combination of "something I know" and "something I have", but could it work for a VM also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authentication** is about making sure that the peer (say, a connecting client) is who they claim to be; this is the normal first step which enables *authorization*, i.e. the process of deciding whether the access ought to be granted or not. The important point is that such a thing makes sense only when there is a system which acts as gatekeeper for an important service, e.g. the system contains sensitive data.

A VM image, that the attacker might possibly steal a copy of, is **not** such a system. By definition, an attacker who steals an image of a VM can inspect it at will, booting it up, seeing its file, reading its memory, and so on. To make an analogy, imagine the VM as a city; the SSH and 2FA and whatsnot is a big fortified wall encircling the city, with sturdy doors and dozens of guards armed with swords and pikes; they will grant access only to people who know the passcode and are vouched for by a citizen. For the attacker, stealing the VM is like having some choppers and landing a few platoons of marines on the city central plaza; the efficiency of the wall and the guards against such a scenario is, at best, questionable.

So yeah, against an attacker who can read all the stored data (that's what happens with a stolen VM image) you need *confidentiality*, and that calls for **encryption**. You can actually forget this VM business and SSH; for the security you want, it totally misses the point.

Comment: @Tomas great answer, what about if we remove the VM from this question and put the system on a Raspberry Pi?